# which is better? money or progress in the profession?

Tags: job-offer

I am a student game developer that I had a job offer but I didn't accept it altough it have good earnings because I guess I can't progress there.I didn't accept because they haven't information about game developing and they tell me you should work alone but I think when I success that I have teamwork.finally i find small team but they tell me we can't give you money and I guess I can progress there.
I hate money just i need it since it's same Barrier for my progression.please tell me what should i do: 1.money 2.progress
if you tell me "progress" but I have financial problems i need money.how can I stop worrying?

Comment: Which do you think you need more right now? Nobody else can answer this for you. Remember that there may be other jobs out there which give you both, in various mixtures; this isn't a pure either/or. And one job is not your entire career; you can change jobs later when your needs change.

Comment: For what it's worth, the Workplace SE would tell you the same thing.

Comment: Workplace SE would also probably close this as *advice on what to do are not practical answerable questions (e.g. "what job should I take?", or "what skills should I learn?")*.

Comment: Do what you love; money will follow =)

Comment: that's right @MackieeE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't give you specific advice without a ton more details, and even then the "right" answer depends on your own preferences.  You need to determine your own goals.  I can make a couple of observations you might think about, though.

- Frequently, career progress and lifetime wealth are completely compatible goals, but they may be incompatible with *current* income.  That is, the best way to maximize your wealth is often to take a career-advancing job that may not pay highly, work it for a few years, then change jobs and repeat.  Each time you change, make sure you are landing at a higher position than your last.  If you are successful you will end up making a lot of money and truly advancing your career.  What you give up is stability and comfort.
- Normally I'd say if you are experiencing financial distress, it's time to take a high paying job for at least a while while you get your feet under you.  However, since you mention you are a student, I infer that you are young and may be in a position to borrow or just live a very poor life while you get established.  These are both normal for that time of life.
- Just because a job doesn't involve working on a team doesn't mean it won't advance your career.  Advancing your career frequently means having lots of lines of relevant work on your resume.  You should keep each job for at least a few years (maybe 3) so you don't look like a quitter, but in terms of marketability, lots of different kinds of experiences are good, including working alone.
- You haven't mentioned your alternative jobs. If the question is whether to take a job that's not so great or to be unemployed, the not-so-great job is pretty much always better.  You won't enhance your career at all by not working.
- In terms of worrying, I'd say having a successful and ambitious life will always involve worry.  You need to channel that energy to something positive.  Make a plan of what you want to do with your life, when you will pay off your debts, and what your ultimate career goal is.  Make a budget and figure out how you will get by.  Write it down.  This will help turn unhelpful stress into helpful action.

Good luck.